# Solving a system of linear equations!

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not sure how to solve a system of linear equations of this nature:

1. s(Y-T)= G-T-bi
2. M/P=h×Y-gi

Here's how I tried to solve it:

[image: Problem solving]

I'm doing something wrong but I do not know what.

I hope that someone can help me with this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What are the variables you are solving for and what are the givens?

Answer (score 1):

What you got is the same as the answer because 
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{bh+gs}\left(gG-gT+gsT+\frac{bM}{p}\right)&=\frac{g}{bh+gs}\left(G-T+sT+\frac{bM}{gp}\right)\\&=\frac{g}{hb+gs}\left(\frac{bM}{gp}-T+sT+G\right)\\&=\frac{g}{hb+gs}\left(\frac{bM}{gp}-(1-s)\times T+G\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. "Transfer" the $g$ from the expression in the brackets to the fraction by dividing the former and multiplying the latter by $g$.

Is this macroeconomics stuff?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you very much for all your help and useful information!

Yes, this was macroeconomics stuff (it's really not my thing).